# What's exactly the difference between using strand::post and io_service::post with strand::wrap?

Tags: boost, boost-asio

In my understanding, posting handlers to a `strand` object means:

- Only one of the posted handlers is executed at a time.
- The handlers are invoked in order.

Posting handlers directly to an `io_service` object and wrapping them by `strand::wrap` also means that only one of the posted handlers is executed at a time, but not in order.

Is there any other difference? And how can I run two (or more) different kind of works (so, different handlers/functions) parallel (in different threads) by using `strand`?

Answer (score 1):

If you want them to run in parallel don't use stands. Strands are for serializing. Just post to the service and have the service run in a thread pool.

But you bring up a good point that I would like someone to answer. What exactly is the 
difference? If wrap serializes all handlers then how could they get out of order, i.e. seems like it does the same thing as posting through a strand? Where would you use one over the other?

Answer (score 0):

In fact, `strand` is a queue, so posting a handler to `io_service` by `wrap` is same as not to wrap because each time you post it, you do in a distinct temp `strand` (each queue contains only one handler -- all those handlers can be executed concurrently because they are not in the same `strand`). If you need serialized handlers, they must be wrapped by the same `strand` object (which therefore contains more than one handler).